# Angular login visivel no header da requisição

Tags: angular, header, cors, httpclient

Galera, Boa tarde.

Preciso de uma ajuda. Meu backend foi escrito em nodejs e esta no IIS. Meu frontend esta em angular e ainda esta em minha maquina sendo debugado. Minha pagina de login esta funcionando como o esperado, conectando sem problemas. Mas quando o aplicativo manda a requisição para o backend é possível pegar o username e o password tanto via browser quanto usando o wireshark. Como que consigo ocultar estas informações? Exemplo: quando usamos a caixa de login do browser para este tipo de autenticação, ele não deixa visivel es informações de login e senha.

meu código:

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<User> {

     const body = { username: username, password: password };
     const headers = new HttpHeaders();
     headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));
     headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

     return this.http
               .post<User>(`${BASE_URL}/sign-in`, body, { headers: headers })
               .do(user => (this.user = user));
}
```

imagem do wireshark apos logar no aplicativo:
[image: Wireshark]

Comment: Isso acontece pois você **não** está utilizando **SSL** em seu site.

Answer (score 0):

Para ocultar estas informações é necessário a instalação de um certificado SSL no seu backend.
O Certificado funciona encriptando os dados entre o servidor e cliente.

> O protocolo SSL provê a privacidade e a integridade de dados entre
>   duas aplicações que comuniquem pela internet. Isso ocorre por
>   intermédio da autenticação das partes envolvidas e da cifragem dos
>   dados transmitidos entre as partes. Ainda, esse protocolo ajuda a
>   prevenir que intermediários entre as duas extremidades das
>   comunicações obtenham acesso indevido ou falsifiquem os dados que
>   estão sendo transmitidos[...]. fonte: [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)

Existem vários tipos e níveis de certificados SSL, bem como várias certificadoras.

Um gratuito, que inclusive eu uso, é o [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Como configurar em nodejs:
https://gist.github.com/davestevens/c9e437afbb41c1d5c3ab

Comment: Entendi. Então não preciso fazer nada no frontend e sim no backend. Como meu fronted esta rodando em uma maquina e o backend em outra, imaginei que precisaria fazer algo deste tipo. Teria alguma aplicação de exemplo no github? e obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Encontrei um tutorial de como configurar um ssl no nodejs. https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-ssl

Comment: Obrigado. Vou estudar um pouco mais estas configurações.